# Call Second Function in a Scriptfile

Tags: javascript, php

```
var CustomerBoxesLoad = function () {

    var handleAjaxBoxesSelectedCountry = function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'ajax/selectbox/country_selected.php',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data) {

                var select = $("#countryCodeBox"), options = '';
                select.empty();      

                options += "<option value='0'>Select ...</option>";              

                for(var i=0;i<data.length; i++)
                {
                    options += "<option value='"+data[i].id+"'>"+ data[i].name +"</option>";              
                }

                select.append(options);

            }
        }); 

    }

    var handleAjaxBoxesCustomerType = function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'ajax/selectbox/customer_type.php',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data) {

                var select = $("#customerTypeBox"), options = '';
                select.empty();      

                options += "<option value='0'>Select ...</option>";     

                for(var i=0;i<data.length; i++)
                {
                    options += "<option value='"+data[i].id+"'>"+ data[i].name +"</option>";
                }

                select.append(options);

            }
        });     


    }


    return {
        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function () {

        handleAjaxBoxesSelectedCountry();
        handleAjaxBoxesCustomerType();

        }

    };

}();
```

I have a function calling from a PHP file. At the end of the PHP file i am calling the Ajax function:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
        CustomerBoxesLoad.init();   
    });
```

All the Ajax select boxes filling works good. Now i want to trigger the Ajax script from a (a href="") tag. But the function will not trigger like this:

```
a href="javascript:handleAjaxBoxesSelectedCountry();">Refresh Select Box
```

THIS reference to the JavaScript dont work!!

Comment: Create a wrapper function in global scope that would call your method, and use that one instead.

Answer (score 0):

add another function to your return:

```
 return {
    //main function to initiate the module
    init: function () {
        handleAjaxBoxesSelectedCountry();
        handleAjaxBoxesCustomerType();
    }

    handleAjaxBoxesSelectedCountry: function () {
        handleAjaxBoxesSelectedCountry();
    }
};
```

and the 'a' tag:

```
<a href="javascript:CustomerBoxesLoad().init();return false;">STH</a>
```

Comment: I dont want to use the CustomerBoxesLoad() event. I need to call the sub function in this function 'handleAjaxBoxesSelectedCountry()'.

Comment: according to your code the "CustomerBoxesLoad" is a function you declared and it returns a class/object containing another function named "init". So to call init function in return of function "CustomerBoxesLoad", we need to first call this function then call init function from the returned object.

Comment: Please understand that the CustomerBoxesLoad function works on the window load event. No problem with that. Right now i am searching for a way to reload the function 'handleAjaxBoxesSelectedCountry' function in the javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself:

```
return {

    //main function to initiate the module
    init: function () {

        handleAjaxBoxesCountry();
        handleAjaxBoxesCustomerType();

    },
    init_country: function () {
        handleAjaxBoxesCountry();
    },
    init_type: function () {
        handleAjaxBoxesCustomerType();
    }       

};
```